# update did something to my wifi adapter

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, dual-boot, drivers

Ok I am running dual OS windows xp and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I have a Belkin N600 dual band wifi adapter F9L1101v2

Normally my adapter doesn't work with linux cause for whatever reason belkin doesn't support linux on all their devices it took me a good solid hour the first time to get it working that was like over a month ago

I just recently updated my ubuntu and now my wifi adapter isn't being recognized by ubuntu

I'll say this now I've only had ubuntu a short time I barely know anything so if you give me an answer please explain it so a noob can understand

Output

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Previous was wrong for a USB dongle, sry.

Comment: ok I got the output up took a while to figure how to post it correctly

Comment: OK. I see what it is. I will pack it as dkms in some time, add it to my answer and ping you.

Comment: Can I ask what a dkms is? Like I said I'm very new to Linux. I don't really know commands for the terminal and stuff. I got Ubuntu after mirco$oft dropped support for windows xp. I don't have the cash to just go out and get a new computer. I consider myself more tech savvy then the average person. I know how to hunt for the information I need. But in this case I needed expert guidance. I thank you very much for helping me as well.

Comment: DKMS will build and install this driver automatically after kernel upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably compiled a driver from source. After kernel upgrade it stopped working this is normal. You will have to re-install it each time.

I packaged this driver from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git as dkms and pushed it to ppa.

I suggest uninstalling the driver you have first, so there are no conflicts. If you did not delete that rtl8192 folder, run

```
cd rtl8192du
sudo make uninstall
```

Now you can install same driver from ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192du-dkms
```

And you will not have to re-install it after kernel upgrades any more.

Comment: This is probably it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176114&p=12799964#post12799964

Comment: I did not make a dkms for rtl8192du. But Larry Finger accepts my pull requests with that. It is not hard, same as in rtl8192cu. Just add a dkms.conf and install using dkms. I will push it to ppa, when have time.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help guys I managed to fix it on my own. I went back to the page where I got my drivers the first time. http://goo.gl/z8kE9G It mentioned doing stuff every time there is a kernel upgrade.

Comment: @Haze33E  But if you want to get a solution with not having to reinstall each time you upgrade kernel, then ping me in a day or two.

Comment: @Pilot6 that would be great, I ran those commands you gave me but the 2nd one doesn't do anything. If you meant for me to run it as one command that does nothing either. I'll post the output of the first one.

Comment: @Haze33E That are not 2 commands, but one.

Comment: @Pilot6 I had another Kernel update which seems to have broken the dkms you made for me. I updated rebooted and no wi-fi I rebooted again just to check and still broken. I had to install from the file again to get back online. Don't know what happened if you have any ideas that would be great.